# Angularjs for loop promises callback

Tags: angularjs, http

I was wondering if there is any possibility to get a callback at the end of a series of requests. I'm attaching an example code so you can better understand :

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.array.length; i++) {
    factory.getX($scope.array[i].id)
        .success(function (_response) {
            /* call function if it's the last request in the for loop*/
        })
        .error(function (_err) {
            $scope.displayAlert(_err)
        })
}
```

In the factory object, I have a `$http.get()` function. Thanks !

Comment: take a look at `$q.all`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have a callback when all the requests are completed you could save all the promises that are created in a array and make a common promise with `var allRequests = $q.all(arrayOfPromises)`

You could then do `allRequests.then(callback)` to implement your callback

Comment: can you, please, be more explicit on saving all the promises in an array ?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all, I've solved the problem like this :

```
 var promises = $scope.array.map(function (item) {
                        return factory.getX(item.id)
                            .success(function (_response) {

                            })
                            .error(function (_err) {
                                $scope.displayAlert(_err)
                            })
                    })

 $q.all(promises).then(function () {
        console.log("Solved all the promises")
    }
```